# Ruby Native Extension - use other C extension gem

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-native-extensions

I am writing ruby c extension which has a dependency on another C extension.
currently, I am calling the other C extension via `rb_funcall` I would like to call the C extension's function directly (include its header and call the public function)

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe possible using `dlopen` to load the library and `dlsym` to get the function pointers, but I have no idea if that is safe.

Comment: Why not joining ( ``#include``) source code? This is not Your code?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Nakilon nope, I thought about adding the other C extension code to my code but it added complexity to the project that I don't want to handle